# How to check if a SMS was actually delivered to the recipients phone?

Tags: android, sms, send, android-pendingintent, smsmanager

I would like to check if a sms was actually delivered to the recipients phone.

All examples I found so far are displaying "SMS delivered" even when the recipients phone is turned off. So I appreciate any ideas and code-snippets.

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, new 
Intent(SENT), 0);
PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0,new 
Intent(DELIVERED), 0);
String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";


// ---when the SMS has been sent---

    mContext.registerReceiver(
            new BroadcastReceiver()
            {    
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context arg0,Intent arg1)
                {
                    switch(getResultCode())
                    {
                     case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                     break;
                     case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                     break;
                     case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                     break;
                     case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                     break;
                     case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                     break;
                    }
                }
            }, new IntentFilter(SENT));


    // ---when the SMS has been delivered---

    mContext.registerReceiver(
            new BroadcastReceiver()
            {

                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context arg0,Intent arg1)
                {
                    switch(getResultCode())
                    {
                     case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                     break;
                     case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                     break;
                    }
                }
            }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));


SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null,message,sentPI, deliveredPI);
```

Comment: Doesn't make sense. Android will normally broadcast the DELIVERED event when the SMS has been delivered to the recipient. You may have a problem with your telephony provider that it is generating the delivery reports even if the recipient's phone is off. Try with a different service provider.

Comment: Well, I don't think the service provider is the reason fot his behaviour as the build in sms application of android differs between "sms send", sms delivered" and "sms not delivered". If the recipients phone is turned of and the sms can't be delivered, the sms app shows a red exclamation mark. If the sms was delivered sucessfully, the app shows a green tick. So maybe the DELIVERED event is not the right approach?

Comment: Well you can add logging and see what you are getting. You should only get the "delivered" event when the SMS arrives at the recipient's phone.